# How to change an external variable in map or foreach operator in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need change an external variable in map or foreach operator in Scala, code is as below:

```
val data = sc.textFile(inputFile)
var examMap = Map[String, Int]()
data.map(sample => {
    if (examMap.contains(sample)) {
        val value = examMap.get(sample).get
        examMap -= sample
        examMap += (sample -> (value + 1))
    }
    else {
        examMap += (sample -> 1)
    }
})
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It smells a mutability which could be replaced by `foldLeft` or custom recursion

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a minimal, self-contained example that can work for everybody and state what is the unexpected result of it?

Answer (score 1):

A version with immutable values, where we create a tuple for each `sample` occurrence, group by sample identity and sum up common samples before we convert the tupled sample-sums to a `Map[String,Int]`,

```
val data = sc.textFile(inputFile)

val examMap = data.map(sample => (sample, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

@echo is right. Their solution should do what you expect.

One more note:

The problem with your (currrent) solution is that if you run this program is a real cluster environment (not `--master local[*]`), the functions inside the `map` (and other Spark operators) are executed on different workers in parallel on a part of the complete dataset. So, every worker that executes the `map` (or `foreach`) on its partition, will also receive a copy of `examMap` to write to.

Initially, this map is empty, and workers will update their local copies. At the end, when the distributed processing finishes, the control is returned back to the driver (your program). Here, however, the original copy of `examMap` is used - and since all worker updated their local copies, this map will be empty.

While the shown solution is correct and the way to go, you may want to read about [shared variables](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables) on spark